# Getting Segmentation fault in C code while trying to assign a pointer to some object

Tags: c, data-structures, graph, tree

I am trying to solve a question in C language. The problem statement is(reading whole problem is not important for my doubt):

> Given an arbitrary unweighted rooted tree which consists of N nodes.
> The goal of the problem is to find largest distance between two nodes in a tree.
> Distance between two nodes is a number of edges on a path between the nodes (there will be a unique path between any pair of nodes since it is a tree).
> The nodes will be numbered 0 through N - 1.
> The tree is given as an array A, there is an edge between nodes A[i] and i (0 <= i < N). Exactly one of the i's will have A[i] equal to -1, it will be root node.

I made TreeNode and I am storing all next connections TreeNode pointers in array(like adjacency list in graph)

My solution is:

```
/**
 * @input A : Integer array
 * @input n1 : Integer array's ( A ) length
 * 
 * @Output Integer
 */
 
struct TreeNode2 {
    int value;
    struct TreeNode2 *next;
};

struct TreeNode2* createNode(int n)
{
    struct TreeNode2 *node = (struct TreeNode2 *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct TreeNode2));
    node->value = n;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

int maximum(int a,int b)
{
    if(a>b)
    return a;
    
    return b;
}

int dfs(struct TreeNode2 **tree, int node)
{
    if( tree[node] == NULL )
    return 0;
    
    int len1 = 0;
    int len2 = 0;
    
    struct TreeNode2 *ptr = tree[node];
    
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        int curr = dfs(tree, (ptr->value));
        if( curr > len1 )
        {
            len1 = curr;
        }
        else if(curr > len2)
        {
            len2 = curr;
        }
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    return maximum( len1 + len2 , maximum( len1 , len2 ) + 1 );
}

int solve(int* A, int n1) 
{
    struct TreeNode2 *tree[n1];
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
    {
        tree[i] = NULL;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
    {
        if(A[i] != -1)
        {
            
            struct TreeNode2 *temp = tree[i];
            struct TreeNode2 *newNode = createNode(A[i]);
            tree[i] = newNode;
            newNode->next = temp;
            
            // printf("A[i] = %d \n",A[i]);
            
            struct TreeNode2 *temp2 = tree[ A[i] ];
            struct TreeNode2 *newNode2 = createNode(i);
            tree[ A[i] ] = newNode2;
            newNode2->next = temp2;
            
        }
    }
    int ans = dfs(tree, 0);
    return ans;
}
```

I'm getting the segmentation fault the moment I am adding

```
tree[ A[i] ] = newNode2;
```

in solve function in forloop for input `-1, 0`. I tried `tree[A[i]] = NULL` (it worked). The problem is when `A[i] = 0`, `tree[0] = NULL` is working but `tree[0] = newNode2` is not working why.?

Comment: Code is incomplete. Please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In particular, provide the code that calls the function and any other code needed to repro the problem.

Comment: What is the value of `A[i]` when the error happens? Is it less than `n1`?

Comment: @Barmar A[i] = 0 when it happened. I checked it is definitely not greater than n1

Comment: @kaylum I'm solving problem on interviewbit, on that platform they only provide a function to complete it.

Comment: Doesn't matter. To debug the issue you yourself should be constructing your own test cases. You can't rely on code you don't have access to and you shouldn't be just submitting your code without having done thorough testing with your own test code. That's just standard procedure for software development and debugging.

Comment: I'm guessing but is the original problem: https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/largest-distance-between-nodes-of-a-tree/ ?

Comment: @CraigEstey yes

Answer (score 0):

From the link, the example explanation shows that node 0 has *three* [direct] children (nodes, 1, 2, 3).

---

I could be wrong about this, but I think an algorithm that works is as follows:

As we build the tree, we remember the node with the maximum depth.

After the tree is built, we can traverse it to find the maximum depth of any [leaf] node that is *not* max node we found when building.

The solution is the sum of the depth of those two nodes

---

Here's some code I wrote to do that. I submitted it for test input and it passed.

**Edit:** I've revised the test and now it passes all tests but exceeds the time limit in the "Efficiency" test.

I expected as much because of the [seeming] O(n^2) but I wanted to try a non-standard approach that doesn't use "visited".

I added some code to dump a text file that can be fed to `graphviz` with `-DGRAPH`. It produces an output file: `grf`. To process this, do:

```
dot -Tsvg < grf > grf.svg
```

Then, you can point your browser to the `grf.svg` file to display the graph.

Anyway, here's the working but slow code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define sysfault(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        printf(_fmt); \
        exit(1); \
    } while (0)

#ifndef ROOTLEAF
#define ROOTLEAF    0
#endif

#if ROOTLEAF
#define PTROK(_ptr)     (_ptr != NULL)
#else
#define PTROK(_ptr)     1
#endif

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        printf(_fmt); \
    } while (0)
#define nodeshow(_node,_tag) \
    do { \
        _nodeshow(_node,_tag); \
    } while (0)
#ifndef GRAPH
#define GRAPH
#endif
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
    } while (0)
#define nodeshow(_node,_tag) \
    do { \
    } while (0)
#endif

#define MAXNODE     40000

#define COUNTOF(_arr) \
    (sizeof(_arr) / sizeof(_arr[0]))

typedef struct node node_t;
struct node {
    int paridx;
    int depth;

    node_t *parent;
    node_t *next;

    node_t *cldhead;
    node_t *cldtail;

    node_t *leaf;
};

static node_t *root = NULL;
static node_t *lhsbest = NULL;
static node_t *rhsbest = NULL;
static int Acnt = -1;
static node_t nodelist[MAXNODE + 1] = { 0 };
static int soldepth;
static FILE *xfgrf;

static char *
tlsbuf(void)
{
    static int bufidx = 0;
    static char buf[16][1000];
    char *bp;

    bp = buf[bufidx];
    ++bufidx;
    bufidx %= 16;

    *bp = 0;

    return bp;
}

static int
nodenum(node_t *node)
{

    if (node != NULL)
        return node - nodelist;
    else
        return -1;
}

static char *
nodexid(node_t *lhs,node_t *rhs)
{
    int lhsnum = nodenum(lhs);
    int rhsnum = nodenum(rhs);
    int tmp;
    char *buf;

    if (lhsnum > rhsnum) {
        tmp = lhsnum;
        lhsnum = rhsnum;
        rhsnum = tmp;
    }

    buf = tlsbuf();

    sprintf(buf,"%d,%d",lhsnum,rhsnum);

    return buf;
}

static void
_nodeshow(node_t *node,const char *tag)
{

#ifdef DEBUG
    if (node != NULL) {
        dbgprt("nodeshow: %s node=%d paridx=%d depth=%d\n",
            tag,nodenum(node),node->paridx,node->depth);
    }
    else
        dbgprt("nodeshow: %s null\n",tag);
#endif

}

// newnode -- create new node;
static node_t *
newnode(int idx,node_t *par)
{
    node_t *node;

    node = &nodelist[idx];

    if (par != NULL) {
        node->paridx = nodenum(par);
        node->depth = par->depth + 1;
    }
    else
        node->paridx = -1;

    node->parent = par;

    return node;
}

// fastfind -- find node based on i from A[i]
static node_t *
fastfind(int value)
{
    node_t *node;

    node = &nodelist[value];
    nodeshow(node,"fastfind");

    return node;
}

// addchild -- attach child node to parent
static void
addchild(node_t *par,node_t *cld)
{

    cld->next = par->cldhead;
    par->cldhead = cld;
}

int
pathok(node_t *cur)
{
    int okay;

    if (ROOTLEAF)
        okay = (cur != NULL);
    else
        okay = (cur != NULL) && (cur != root);

    return okay;
}

int
pathcost(node_t *lhs,node_t *rhs)
{
    int lhsok;
    int rhsok;
    int cost;

    dbgprt("pathcost: ENTER lhs=%d rhs=%d xid=%s\n",
        nodenum(lhs),nodenum(rhs),nodexid(lhs,rhs));

    cost = 0;

    if (lhs == root) {
        dbgprt("pathcost: QWKROOT\n");
        cost = rhs->depth;
        lhs = NULL;
        rhs = NULL;
    }

    while (1) {
        if ((lhs == NULL) && (rhs == NULL))
            break;

        // join at lower level than root
        if (lhs == rhs)
            break;

#ifdef DEBUG
        nodeshow(lhs,"LHS");
        nodeshow(rhs,"RHS");
#endif

        lhsok = pathok(lhs);
        rhsok = pathok(rhs);

        if (PTROK(lhs) && PTROK(rhs) && (lhs->depth > rhs->depth)) {
            //nodeshow(lhs,"LHSDEEP");

            if (lhsok) {
                cost += 1;
                dbgprt("pathcost: LCOST/D cost=%d\n",cost);
                lhs = lhs->parent;
            }

            continue;
        }

        if (PTROK(lhs) && PTROK(rhs) && (rhs->depth > lhs->depth)) {
            //nodeshow(lhs,"RHSDEEP");

            if (rhsok) {
                cost += 1;
                dbgprt("pathcost: RCOST/D cost=%d\n",cost);
                rhs = rhs->parent;
            }

            continue;
        }

        if (PTROK(lhs) && lhsok) {
            cost += 1;
            dbgprt("pathcost: LCOST/S cost=%d\n",cost);
            lhs = lhs->parent;
        }

        if (PTROK(rhs) && rhsok) {
            cost += 1;
            dbgprt("pathcost: RCOST/S cost=%d\n",cost);
            rhs = rhs->parent;
        }
    }

    dbgprt("pathcost: EXIT cost=%d\n",cost);

    return cost;
}

void
search1(void)
{
    int curcost;
    node_t *end = &nodelist[Acnt];
    node_t *leafbase = NULL;
    node_t *lhs = NULL;
    node_t *rhs = NULL;
    int bestcost = 0;
    int leafcnt = 0;

    // link all leaf nodes together
    for (rhs = nodelist;  rhs < end;  ++rhs) {
        if (ROOTLEAF) {
            if (rhs != nodelist) {
                if (rhs->cldhead != NULL)
                    continue;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (rhs->cldhead != NULL)
                continue;
        }

        nodeshow(rhs,"ISLEAF");

        if (leafbase == NULL)
            leafbase = rhs;

        if (lhs != NULL)
            lhs->leaf = rhs;

        lhs = rhs;
        ++leafcnt;
    }

    lhsbest = NULL;
    rhsbest = NULL;

    do {
        if (leafcnt == 1) {
            bestcost = leafbase->depth;
            lhsbest = leafbase;
            break;
        }

        for (lhs = leafbase;  lhs != NULL;  lhs = lhs->leaf) {
            nodeshow(lhs,"LEAFLHS");
            for (rhs = lhs->leaf;  rhs != NULL;  rhs = rhs->leaf) {
                curcost = pathcost(lhs,rhs);
                if (curcost > bestcost) {
                    lhsbest = lhs;
                    nodeshow(lhsbest,"LHSGUD");

                    rhsbest = rhs;
                    nodeshow(rhsbest,"RHSGUD");

                    bestcost = curcost;
                }
            }
        }

    } while (0);

    nodeshow(lhsbest,"LHSBEST");
    nodeshow(rhsbest,"RHSBEST");

    soldepth = bestcost;
}

int
pathcost2(node_t *lhs,node_t *rhs)
{
    int lhsok;
    int rhsok;
    int cost;

    dbgprt("pathcost2: ENTER lhs=%d rhs=%d xid=%s\n",
        nodenum(lhs),nodenum(rhs),nodexid(lhs,rhs));

    cost = 0;

    if (lhs == root) {
        dbgprt("pathcost: QWKROOT\n");
        cost = rhs->depth;
        lhs = NULL;
        rhs = NULL;
    }

    while (1) {
        if ((lhs == NULL) && (rhs == NULL))
            break;

        // join at lower level than root
        if (lhs == rhs)
            break;

#ifdef DEBUG
        nodeshow(lhs,"LHS");
        nodeshow(rhs,"RHS");
#endif

        lhsok = pathok(lhs);
        rhsok = pathok(rhs);

        if (PTROK(lhs) && PTROK(rhs) && (lhs->depth > rhs->depth)) {
            //nodeshow(lhs,"LHSDEEP");

            if (lhsok) {
                cost += 1;
                dbgprt("pathcost: LCOST/D cost=%d\n",cost);
                lhs = lhs->parent;
            }

            continue;
        }

        if (PTROK(lhs) && PTROK(rhs) && (rhs->depth > lhs->depth)) {
            //nodeshow(lhs,"RHSDEEP");

            if (rhsok) {
                cost += 1;
                dbgprt("pathcost: RCOST/D cost=%d\n",cost);
                rhs = rhs->parent;
            }

            continue;
        }

        if (PTROK(lhs) && lhsok) {
            cost += 1;
            dbgprt("pathcost: LCOST/S cost=%d\n",cost);
            lhs = lhs->parent;
        }

        if (PTROK(rhs) && rhsok) {
            cost += 1;
            dbgprt("pathcost: RCOST/S cost=%d\n",cost);
            rhs = rhs->parent;
        }
    }

    dbgprt("pathcost2: EXIT cost=%d\n",cost);

    return cost;
}

void
search2(void)
{
    int curcost;
    node_t *end = &nodelist[Acnt];
    node_t *leafbase = NULL;
    node_t *lhs = NULL;
    node_t *rhs = NULL;
    int bestcost = 0;
    int leafcnt = 0;
    int maxdepth = 0;

    lhsbest = NULL;
    rhsbest = NULL;

    // link all leaf nodes together
    for (rhs = nodelist;  rhs < end;  ++rhs) {
        if (rhs->cldhead != NULL)
            continue;

        nodeshow(rhs,"ISLEAF");

        if (rhs->depth > maxdepth) {
            maxdepth = rhs->depth;
            rhsbest = rhs;
        }

        if (leafbase == NULL)
            leafbase = rhs;

        if (lhs != NULL)
            lhs->leaf = rhs;

        lhs = rhs;
        ++leafcnt;
    }

    do {
        bestcost = maxdepth;
        lhsbest = leafbase;

        if (leafcnt == 1) {
            bestcost = leafbase->depth;
            lhsbest = leafbase;
            break;
        }

        for (lhs = leafbase;  lhs != NULL;  lhs = lhs->leaf) {
            nodeshow(lhs,"LEAFLHS");
            for (rhs = lhs->leaf;  rhs != NULL;  rhs = rhs->leaf) {
                curcost = pathcost(lhs,rhs);
                if (curcost > bestcost) {
                    lhsbest = lhs;
                    nodeshow(lhsbest,"LHSGUD");

                    rhsbest = rhs;
                    nodeshow(rhsbest,"RHSGUD");

                    bestcost = curcost;
                }
            }
        }
    } while (0);

    nodeshow(lhsbest,"LHSBEST");
    nodeshow(rhsbest,"RHSBEST");

    soldepth = bestcost;
}

void
dograph(void)
{
#ifdef GRAPH
    int idx;
    node_t *cur;
    node_t *par;
    char *bp;
    char buf[100];

    xfgrf = fopen("grf","w");
    fprintf(xfgrf,"digraph {\n");

    for (idx = 0;  idx < Acnt;  ++idx) {
        cur = &nodelist[idx];

        bp = buf;
        bp += sprintf(bp,"label=\"N%d D%d\"",nodenum(cur),cur->depth);
        if (cur == rhsbest)
            bp += sprintf(bp," color=Green");
        if (cur == lhsbest)
            bp += sprintf(bp," color=Red");
        fprintf(xfgrf,"\tN%d [%s]\n",nodenum(cur),buf);

        par = cur->parent;
        if (par != NULL)
            fprintf(xfgrf,"\tN%d -> N%d\n",nodenum(par),nodenum(cur));
    }

    fprintf(xfgrf,"}\n");
    fclose(xfgrf);
#endif
}

int
solve(int *A,int argcnt)
{
    int idx;
    int parval;
    node_t *par;

    if (root != NULL) {
        memset(nodelist,0,sizeof(nodelist));
        root = NULL;
    }

    // find the root node
    // FIXME/CAE -- probably always the first
    Acnt = argcnt;
    for (idx = 0;  idx < Acnt;  ++idx) {
        int parval = A[idx];

        if (parval == -1) {
            dbgprt("solve: ROOT idx=%d\n",idx);
            root = newnode(idx,NULL);
            break;
        }
    }

    // build all child nodes:
    for (idx = 0;  idx < Acnt;  ++idx) {
        parval = A[idx];
        if (parval == -1)
            continue;

        dbgprt("solve: NODE idx=%d parval=%d\n",idx,parval);

        // find parent
        par = fastfind(parval);

        // create node
        node_t *cur = newnode(idx,par);

        // attach child to parent
        addchild(par,cur);
    }

    // traverse all nodes in the tree to find max distance ...
    search2();

    dograph();

    return soldepth;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your time and efforts but I want to know why that line is giving segmentation fault..?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I caught the problem, actually in this problem tree connection is undirected so the code is stuck in loop inside dfs. I used visited array to solve this issue.

Comment: Congrats! You could/should post your final code in this answer. It might help others in the future. And, you can even give yourself some rep points by upvoting and accepting it.